# Session doesn't work on MAMP

Tags: php, session, localhost, mamp

When i try to run my site on localhost i get an error:

```
Undefined index: log in ... on line 137
```

Within this file there is a line:

```
if (!$_SESSION['log']) { ...
```

Everything works on server, but not on localhost. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you started your session?(`session_start();`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a difference between the level of error reporting between the server and your local setup.

If you want to check if the variable is set (assuming that a session has been started...), you should use:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['log'])) {
```

Or if you want to check if it is not set and / or empty or `false`:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['log'])) {
```

Both will not generate any warnings for non-set variables or array indices.

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't working "on server," but is instead just not showing the error message to the page.

You can fix the warning re: the index by changing your if statement to this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['log']) && !$_SESSION['log']) {
```

Or to whatever condition you need it to be.

Comment: that if statement will never fire. If the first clause evaluates to true, the second will always evaluate false.

Comment: Check your logic again. I think you'll find that isset() != empty(). If the value of $_SESSION['log'] is set to **false**, it **will be set** and **not true**. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php